# Hadoop version not found while building my Play app

Tags: hadoop, sbt, ivy, mahout, playframework-2.3

In my build.sbt of my Play 2.3 application I switch from

"org.apache.mahout" % "mahout-core" % "0.9"

to

"org.apache.mahout" % "mahout-mr" % "0.10.0"

Now on compile I'm getting

[warn]  module not found: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client;${hadoop.version}

To make it working in mahout-mr\ivy-0.10.0.xml I replaced the placeholder ${hadoop.version} with 2.4.1. 
However, this more a hack than a solution.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because mahot expects a hadoop installation to be available. In my case, adding `"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.6.0"` to build.sbt fixed this particular problem.